# Cannot understand if this is circular dependency or Clang

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I am on Clang/OS X Yosemite and my project was using Eigen fine. Then I introduced an external library that also uses Eigen and I now have this compilation error:

```
/usr/local/include/Eigen3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h:516:13: Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Eigen::internal::quaternionbase_assign_impl<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>, 3, 1>'
```

This is seems to come from a declaration in the library:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
```

And this is the code where I use the Quaternion:

```
Eigen::Quaternion<double> q, q_wv, q_ic, q_cv;
q_cv = _poseHandler->GetAttitudeMeasurement();  // problem here
```

First of all, since that include takes into account Core and Geometry, I do not think it's a header missing. Then I do not understand the "undefined template" error, because the internal template is declared in the same header if you go look into it. So I am left with a question: what is wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I changed everything in the library to use the `import` directive instead of `include`, but it didn't fix the problem. Also, if I import `<Eigen/Core>` in the class that is using the library it is fine, but not if I import `<Eigen/Geometry>`.

Comment: Does that external library that also uses Eigen include the Eigen headers, and does it perhaps use a different version of Eigen?

Comment: No, I have the source of the library included in my project, so using the same version.

Comment: Hm...this might be a circular include. Run with -E option, look at the preprocessed output with an editor.

Comment: Also, you should triple-check that the template for which you are getting the error really is defined. Check exact spelling, etc. BTW, you say that it's *declared* in the same header. Did you mean really mean declared as opposed to "defined"? Because if it's only a declaration, then that is not enough.

Comment: It is forward-declared, then defined (but after the line that has the error) in the same file: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/167ce78594dc4e7a4b9ca27fc745e674300e85ff/Eigen/src/Geometry/Quaternion.h?at=default trying to find how to use the -E option in XCode

Comment: OK I am looking at the preprocessor output, how can I figure out if it's a circular include from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this doesn't completely tell you what's wrong, but hopefully will point you in the right direction. The problem is that `quaternionbase_assign_impl` doesn't support 3X1 matrices, it seems. (Unless there is other code that is getting into the translation unit somehow.) There is a forward declaration of it:

```
template<typename Other,
         int OtherRows=Other::RowsAtCompileTime,
         int OtherCols=Other::ColsAtCompileTime>
struct quaternionbase_assign_impl;
```

Then there are two specializations:

```
template<typename Other>
struct quaternionbase_assign_impl<Other,3,3> { ... };
```

and

```
template<typename Other>
struct quaternionbase_assign_impl<Other,4,1> { ... };
```

There is no "generic" definition of the template. Thus, when the compiler tries to instantiate

```
Eigen::internal::quaternionbase_assign_impl<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>, 3, 1>
```

there is no match. Note that the 3X1 comes from the forward declaration, where the default template arguments are given. If you post the full error message, we might be able to track down the beginning of the chain of instantiations that ultimately is trying to cause a 3X1 `quaternionbase_assign_impl` to be instantiated.

Comment: ZOMG I can't believe I didn't bother looking at the actual template parameters, in the end it was a really silly error! The function in question has in fact to return a quaternion, not a 3x1 matrix. Thank you, you unblocked me and also made me learn something very useful! (the compiler error was a bit confusing)